# Using VBA to Copy Vertical Column and Paste Diagonally

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of data, let's call it col A, with say 35 rows of data. How does one loop over this column and then paste each data point in another sheet while incrementing both the column and row for each cycle of the loop. In other words, I seek to paste diagonally in the the second sheet. Is there a simple way to perform such an action in VBA?

Answer (score 3):

Don't loop, have some fun with array manipulation

```
Sub ColumnToDiagonal()
    With Sheet2.Cells.Resize(35, 35)
       .Formula = "=IF(Row()<>Column(), """", sheet1!$A1)"
       .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

*With a tongue-in-cheek dig at A.S.H ;)*

Don't get complicated, do a loop:

```
Sub ColumnToDiagonal()
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To 35
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, r).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, "A").Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: My late grand-pa taught me an old proverb; *Don't make it simple when you can make it complicated* :P

Comment: @A.S.H - I'm surprised that proverb was phrased so simply! ;)